# How to convert a string into double and vice versa?

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert a string into a double and after doing some math on it, convert it back to a string.

How do I do this in Objective-C?

Is there a way to round a double to the nearest integer too?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can convert an NSString into a double with

```
double myDouble = [myString doubleValue];
```

Rounding to the nearest int can then be done as

```
int myInt = (int)(myDouble + (myDouble>0 ? 0.5 : -0.5))
```

I'm honestly not sure if there's a more streamlined way to convert back into a string than

```
NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt];
```

Comment: You don't necessarily want to do this, because different locales format numbers differently.  Some will write "1000" for one thousand, while others will write "1,000" and others "1.000" - which do you get from -[NSString doubleValue]?

Comment: Double is a numeric data type - it does not contain any formatting. Calling [NSString doubleValue] would return 1000 because it's just a number.

Comment: And an NSString cannot contain a number, only a representation of a number.  That representation may be in any of a variety of formats that differ by locale.

Comment: you might want to integrate @Barry Wark's answer in yours, `[[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt] stringValue]`

Comment: What if the string value isn't a valid double string, then 0.0 will be returned by doubleValue.  It seems to me that the solution suggesting the use of NSNumberFormatter is better because if the string doesn't represent a valid double string, then nil is returned.

Comment: I'm with @Kaydell here, it seems like this solution makes it impossible to do any kind of real error handling in the cases where the string can't be parsed as a double (because 0.0 is a valid and reasonable double), which would severely limit the amount of applications this strategy can handle.

Answer (score 72):

To really convert from a string to a number properly, you need to use an instance of [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter) configured for the locale from which you're reading the string.

Different locales will format numbers differently.  For example, in some parts of the world, `COMMA` is used as a decimal separator while in others it is `PERIOD` — and the thousands separator (when used) is reversed.  Except when it's a space.  Or not present at all.

It really depends on the provenance of the input.  The safest thing to do is configure an `NSNumberFormatter` for the way your input is formatted and use `-[NSFormatter numberFromString:]` to get an `NSNumber` from it.  If you want to handle conversion errors, you can use `-[NSFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:]` instead.

Comment: Or you can use a localised scanner, for example one created with [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:], and then [scanner scanDouble:&aDouble] will scan in a double based on the user's current locale.

Answer (score 33):

Adding to olliej's answer, you can convert from an int  back to a string with `NSNumber`'s `stringValue`:

```
[[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt] stringValue]
```

`stringValue` on an `NSNumber` invokes `descriptionWithLocale:nil`, giving you a localized string representation of value. I'm not sure if `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myInt]` will give you a properly localized reprsentation of `myInt`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a working sample of NSNumberFormatter reading localized number String (xCode 3.2.4, osX 10.6), to save others the hours I've just spent messing around. Beware: while it can handle trailing blanks such as "8,765.4 ", this cannot handle leading white space and this cannot handle stray text characters. (Bad input strings: " 8" and "8q" and "8 q".)

```
NSString *tempStr = @"8,765.4";  
     // localization allows other thousands separators, also.
NSNumberFormatter * myNumFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[myNumFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; // happen by default?
[myNumFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
     // next line is very important!
[myNumFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // crucial

NSNumber *tempNum = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:tempStr];
NSLog(@"string '%@' gives NSNumber '%@' with intValue '%i'", 
    tempStr, tempNum, [tempNum intValue]);
[myNumFormatter release];  // good citizen
```

Comment: What does numberFromString return if the string is *not* a valid string?

Comment: numberFromString: returns an NSNumber object. See [NumberFormatting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html)
and [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in apple docs.
(I'm not sure how NSNumber objects encode "not a number" or "bad number", but I see there is a NSNull possible value.)

Comment: @BenClayton numberFromString returns a `nil` valued `NSNumber*` if it can't be parsed. I can't reproduce that problem you had with leading white space and stray text characters, IMO it's working properly. `"     28.5     "` parses as 28.5, and `"gibberish28.5"`, `"28.5gibberish"`, and `"gibberish28.5gibberish"` are all unparseable; `"     2 8 . 5.   "` is unparsable but that's not unusual.

Answer (score 7):

olliej's [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) method is wrong for negative numbers

- 2.4 rounded is 2 (olliej's method gets this right)
- −2.4 rounded is −2 (olliej's method returns -1)

Here's an alternative

```
  int myInt = (int)(myDouble + (myDouble>0 ? 0.5 : -0.5))
```

You could of course use a rounding function from math.h

Answer (score 3):

```
// Converting String in to Double

double doubleValue = [yourString doubleValue];

// Converting Double in to String
NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", doubleValue];
// .20f takes the value up to 20 position after decimal

// Converting double to int

int intValue = (int) doubleValue;
or
int intValue = [yourString intValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

For conversion from a number to a string, how about using the new literals syntax (XCode >= 4.4), its a little more compact.

```
int myInt = (int)round( [@"1.6" floatValue] );

NSString* myString = [@(myInt) description];
```

(Boxes it up as a [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and converts to a string using the [NSObjects' description method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description))

Answer (score 2):

For rounding, you should probably use the C functions defined in math.h.

```
int roundedX = round(x);
```

Hold down Option and double click on `round` in Xcode and it will show you the man page with various functions for rounding different types.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way I know of:

```
float myFloat = 5.3;
NSInteger myInt = (NSInteger)myFloat;
```

Answer (score 1):

from this example here, you can see the the conversions both ways:

```
NSString *str=@"5678901234567890";

long long verylong;
NSRange range;
range.length = 15;
range.location = 0;

[[NSScanner scannerWithString:[str substringWithRange:range]] scanLongLong:&verylong];

NSLog(@"long long value %lld",verylong);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this handy macro:

```
#define STRING(value)               [@(value) stringValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

convert text entered in textfield to integer

```
double mydouble=[_myTextfield.text doubleValue];
```

rounding to the nearest double

```
mydouble=(round(mydouble));
```

rounding to the nearest int(considering only positive values)

```
int myint=(int)(mydouble);
```

converting from double to string

```
myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",mydouble];
```

or

```
NSString *mystring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",mydouble];
```

converting from int to string

```
myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myint];
```

or

```
NSString *mystring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",mydouble];
```