# cast textfield value to double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, casting

i want to sum to values which i get from a textfiel.
how can i cast a textfield value in double value ?

Regards Caglar

Comment: There are no casts from Objective-C objects to primitive types, so it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question: [How to do string conversions in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169925/how-to-do-string-conversions-in-objective-c)

```
double myDouble = [myTextField.text doubleValue];
```

Comment: thank u. i checked your link. but they sum integer values. How can i sum double values ?

Comment: In your view controller, have a double property for the sum, like "@property (assign) double sum;".  In your init method, set "self.sum = 0.0;".  Then, to sum values as they are inputted, you would probably have a button that the user presses after entering each number.  That button should trigger a method (via an IBAction if you're using a nib) that will do "self.sum = self.sum + [myTextField.text doubleValue];" and it should also clear the text field, like " myTextField.text = @""; "

Comment: And of course you can also reset "self.sum = 0.0;" whenever appropriate, such as when the user presses a "Reset" button

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`doubleValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to convert a NSString (from your text field) to a double like so:

```
double myDouble = [myTextField.text doubleValue];
```

This isn't a cast, by the way, it's a conversion. The `doubleValue` method performs a conversion from a string to a double representation. Casts are something you can only perform on primitive numeric types or pointers in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

convert text entered in textfield to integer

```
double mydouble=[_myTextfield.text doubleValue];
```

rounding to the nearest double

```
mydouble=(round(mydouble));
```

rounding to the nearest int(considering only positive values)

```
int myint=(int)(mydouble);
```

converting from double to string

```
myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",mydouble];
```

or

```
NSString *mystring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",mydouble];
```

converting from int to string

```
myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myint];
```

or

```
NSString *mystring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",mydouble];
```