# How do I convert a string into an integer in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, string, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do string conversions in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169925/how-to-do-string-conversions-in-objective-c)

I am trying to convert a user's guess into an integer. How do I do that?

Answer (score 22):

This is trivial in Objective-C...

```
NSString *inputString = @"75";
int value = [inputString intValue];
```

You can also use floatValue, doubleValue or (I believe) even boolValue to convert an NSString to other types. Here is a page that lists some common tasks you may need to perform with strings;

http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString