# Change string to integer in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a string into an integer in objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787461/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-objective-c)

I want to take a string from an UITextField object and convert it into an integer scalar type.

```
NSInteger *ageOfTheUser;
NSString *string;
self.string=age.text;
ageOfTheUser=(int)string;
```

I am getting a warning at ageOfTheUser with 'assigment makes pointer from string cast'.

Comment: I think you want `NSInteger ageOfTheUser;`; no `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `string` is already set to a number, you can simply do:

```
ageOfTheUser = [string integerValue];
```

and you're all set.

There's a difference between `intValue` (which is meant to go to a type of `int`) and `integerValue` (which goes to your declared type of `NSInteger`).

One more thing, get rid of the pointer after your `NSInteger` declaration (i.e. instead of `NSInteger * ageOfTheUser;`, do `NSInteger ageOfTheUser;`).

Answer (score 2):

```
ageOfTheUser = [string intValue];
```

Note you can assign an `int` to an `NSInteger` without any additional syntax.

Comment: this isn't correct because NSString's intValue method returns an `int`, not a `NSInteger`

Comment: Really? Have you tried this and found that it does not work? :)

Comment: Oh sure, it does work (for 32-bit number/architecture).  64-bit is somewhat different.  [Here's a related question that you may find illuminating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870867/why-is-there-an-nsinteger) and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int).

Answer (score 2):

Simple as this:

```
int myAgeInt = [@"30" intValue];
```

Comment: You don't need the stringWithFormat in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

First of all NSInteger is typedef'd to long int, so it's not an object. Just use:

```
NSInteger ageOfTheUser;
```

Converting NSString to int is very simple:

```
ageOfTheUser = [self.string intValue];
```