# How to check if input is double or string in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How do you check if a given input is a string or a double? I tried doing `[self.display.text doubleValue]` and if that's not a valid double, it returns 0, but the problem is that 0 is actually a valid input for an actual double, so the program won't know if it's the default error fallback or an actual valid input.

How do you go around this?

Comment: Use `NSPredicate` and try doing the regexp matching for it.

Comment: @Eimantas So just use `NSPredicate` with a regex such as: `^[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?$` and test against it?

Comment: Yes, but I'd use simpler POSIX `[:number:]` template to check if it matches a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use Regular Expressions and NSPredicate to test if it is a double value.

```
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'"];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@"yourdoublevaluehere"];
```

You might need to adjust the Regular expression as I wroteit off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

`-[NSFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:]` does what you want.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170867/901059).

Answer (score 1):

Do it the 'C' way using `strtod` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strtod.3.html)) as that provides you with the last character parsed:

```
NSString *input = @"123.456";
char *endptr;
double value = strtod([input UTF8String], &endptr);
if (*endptr != '\0')
{
    NSLog(@"input is a string");
}
```