# Decimal point in UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad can't be used in mathematical calculation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I am using the keyboard type: `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` for two `UITextField` objects. 
When trying to perform an addition, I get different results depending on the current locale:

Case 1: US Format: the decimal point appears as `.` as expected. If I add 12.3 (text field 1) + 12.3 (text field 2), the answer will be 24.6. That's what I want. But:

Case 2: Egypt Format: the decimal point appears as `,`. If I repeat the same calculation the answer will be 24. The decimal portion is ignored. Is there a fix for that?

Note: I used the `[textField.text floatValue]` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `floatValue` does non-localized scanning, it expects a "US format".

You can use an NSScanner object for localized scanning of numeric values from a string.

See: [String Programming Guide: Scanners](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html)

Note the last paragraph:

> **Localization**
>
> A scanner bases some of its scanning behavior on a locale, which
>   specifies a language and conventions for value representations.
>   NSScanner uses only the locale’s definition for the decimal separator
>   (given by the key named NSDecimalSeparator). You can create a scanner
>   with the user’s locale by using localizedScannerWithString:, or set
>   the locale explicitly using setLocale:. If you use a method that
>   doesn’t specify a locale, the scanner assumes the default locale
>   values.

See also: [How to do string conversions in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169925/how-to-do-string-conversions-in-objective-c)

Example:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:textField.text];
double mynumber;
if([scanner scanDouble: &mynumber]){
  // do something
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
double number = [[self.myTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@”,” withString:@”.”] doublevalue];
```

this is ok for all the languages.