# UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad Limit Decimal Point and handling localization

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decimal point in UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad can’t be used in mathematical calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487850/decimal-point-in-uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-cant-be-used-in-mathematical-calculat)

I have an iPhone app where we are using the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad for input which has been working fine for us until we have started to localize the application, the problem we now face is that when the language is switched to French or German the decimal point on the keypad changes from a full stop (`.`) to a comma (`,`).

We are currently running this code to restrict the input of multiple decimal points i.e. 12.4.4 with this code it will only allow 12.4 to be entered

This works fine but now we also need to check for the comma and also convert the users input for our calculations if it has a comma

Is there a better way to restrict the input on the keypad for both comma and full stop?

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


NSString *currentText = textField.text;


if ([currentText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].length == 0) {
    return YES;
} else {
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].length == 0) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

}

return NO;
```

}

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to work this out this will validate that the number is in decimal format and accept , or .

Aaron

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber* candidateNumber;

    NSString* candidateString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    range = NSMakeRange(0, [candidateString length]);

    [numberFormatter getObjectValue:&candidateNumber forString:candidateString range:&range error:nil];

    if (([candidateString length] > 0) && (candidateNumber == nil || range.length < [candidateString length])) {
        [numberFormatter release];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        [numberFormatter release];
        return YES; 
    } 
}
```