# Coding for non-English Fonts

Tags: java, c++, c, fonts

I got a typical problem and not sure about which will be most suitable programming language I should use to solve it.

Requirement:

> I would like to type my native language scripts (exactly Tamil, an Indian Language) using US Standard keyboard. Google products (gmail) allow us to type in tamil after choosing it from their drop down box. But the issue is, I would like to type in word processor/Adobe products etc.

There are some ready to use software to accomplish my task after paying them hefty price.

But I would like to code myself in C/C++/Java and make them work.

[This](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf) link provides the Unicode character map for Tamil scripts.

Any guidance or any link reference on how to move forward/implement is deeply appreciated.

**Added:** All i have seen so far in the ready to use software is, they launch the program and start typing in Tamil scripts. Once done, they exit the program and the usual English keyboard is enabled. I would like to know how the launch of the program remap the characters and in what language i should code it.

Comment: You should specify a platform.

Comment: For now, im trying on Linux Machine.

Comment: As you want this to work in existing programs which may or may not be Java, I suspect Java is not the best choice as it's not designed to capture and remap keys for an existing program.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. You are trying to use a font, so set it in the options. Are you searching for editors which are able to display Unicode characters? Or do you want a keyword mapping?

Comment: @LucasHoepner I would like to code for that keyboard mapping. Iam not looking for the editor

Comment: Doesn't Windows itself (and other OSes too) have a keyboard layout or whatchamacallit for this? பாே, கூ ்தாே. Ooops, sorry, should have switched back to the English layout for typing "Yes, it does".

Comment: In that case you will most probably need some kind of preprocessor which runs through your code, does the remapping and then throws the processed text into a compiler.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should look at what is called _input methods_. (X Input Method, Universal Input Method and whatever may have replaced them now).

Comment: Linux distributions, at least Debian and Ubuntu, as far as I know allow inputting Tamil in **all** applications **out of the box**. All you need is to make sure your character encoding is Unicode (should be default these days), add appropriate keyboard in language settings in your desktop environment and tell it to switch keyboard per-application if that's what you want.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes How did you type those tamil scripts? Could you please describe the steps for the same.

Comment: @Learner: I suspect he did it on Windows though; the basic principle is the same in all systems, the exact places to click will be slightly different between Gnome, KDE and Windows. There should be "System Settings" application, there you'll find "Regional Settings", "Keyboard Settings", get a list of keyboards used, click "Add Keyboard", select one appropriate for Tamil and you are set. The dialog will also have option to set keyboard shortcut for switching between the keyboard layouts.

Comment: Yes, on Windows it's on the Control Panel > Regional Settings, then there's a tab where you can pick keyboard layouts. You can add several, and then Alt+Left Shift (by default) will switch between the two. You can also put the "Language Bar" on the taskbar and use it to switch with the mouse and to have an indicator of what is the current layout. I use this all the time to switch between Portuguese (my native language), German (my current location's native language), and English (code's native language :P). I know this can be done Linux as well, because I have used that in the past.

Comment: The point is, I don't think you need to code anything special for any keyboard layout: that's something the system should do for you. You only need to code with awareness that not all characters in your code will be English, or single-byte, or ASCII, or...  (for some things that matters, for other it doesn't).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thank you so much for your valuable input.

Comment: Questions that boil down to "what language should I use" are generally off-topic and non-constructive on SO.  There cannot be one single, correct answer to this question, and the question invites debate and opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal point in UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad can't be used in mathematical calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487850/decimal-point-in-uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-cant-be-used-in-mathematical-calculat)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Windows 7, that should be no problem - Windows support multiple keyboard layouts and corresponding fonts and codepages. I just installed support for Tamil keyboards (although I have no idea what the symbols mean) and wrote (and translated) this little Program in MSVC2010:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  auto ந = 5;
  std::string த = "Whatsup?: ";
  std::cout << த << ந << '\n';
}
```

Java as well as C++11 support unicode source code and allow the identifiers to contain unicode characters. This should work seamlessly with any editor and IDE that supports unicode.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your problem you need a wrapper of Tamil letters on the English letters.

I think you should use the English letter mapping to you Tamil letter because you don't have Tamil keyboard.

So for each key on the keyboard like `A` , `B` and all you need to map to you Tamil corresponding letters.

When you input a `char` from keyboard then it will check the `ASCII` value of that letter and using the table or map you can get the corresponding `wchar_t` letter and print it accordingly.