# How can I convert a string to an integer in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do string conversions in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169925/how-to-do-string-conversions-in-objective-c)

How can I convert a string to an integer in Objective-C?

Answer (score 4):

```
int value = [string intValue];
```

Comment: Here is what i am trying to convert `pressure = pressureIN;` I am trying to convert pressureIN which is a string value to pressure which is a int value

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger value=[string integerValue];
```