# Pointer cannot be cast to type 'double'

Tags: objective-c, pointers, casting, double

I want to display more than one annotation on the map at the same time. the problem that I have is that I have all latitude and longitude as NSString...

I want to convert strings to duble so that I can passed to "CLLocationCoordinate2D" instance.. 
but I get error which says:Pointer cannot be cast to type 'double'

```
locationCoordinate.latitude=(double)NearbyLocations.lat;
locationCoordinate.latitude=(double)NearbyLocations.lng;
```

This is a part of the code that I have problem with. However, as you might see that I haven't finished it yet.

```
NSMutableArray *locations= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate;
location *NearbyLocations;
Annotation *annotatedLocations;

//for (int i=0; i < locationOnMap.count;i++) {


    annotatedLocations = [[Annotation alloc]init];

    locationCoordinate.latitude=(double)NearbyLocations.lat;
    locationCoordinate.latitude=(double)NearbyLocations.lng;
    annotatedLocations.coordinate=locationCoordinate;
    annotatedLocations.title=NearbyLocations.lo_name;
    annotatedLocations.subtitle=NearbyLocations.lo_vicinity;
    [locations addObject:annotatedLocations];
//}
```

What can I do to cast point typed string into double

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Comment: Marc, it looks pretty much like Objective-C

Comment: So sorry, I am using Objective-c!!! totally forgot to say that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `NSString` conversion method `doubleValue`. Have a look here: [How to do string conversions in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169925/how-to-do-string-conversions-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

This means you're trying to cast an NSNumber objective-c object to a C primitive type, which is not possible. To add an integer to a dictionary you have to convert it to an NSNumber object. To pull it out, you have to convert it back like this:

```
locationCoordinate.latitude = [NearbyLocations.lat doubleValue];
locationCoordinate.latitude = [NearbyLocations.lng doubleValue];
```