# Converting UILabel value to integer xcode

Tags: uikit

In my program, I need to get the value of a label as an int. How do I do so?

This is the code:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1;

    if ([self.motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable]) {
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.xAxis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",accelerometerData.acceleration.x];
                self.yAxis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",accelerometerData.acceleration.y];
                self.zAxis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",accelerometerData.acceleration.z];
            });
        }]; 
    } else 
        NSLog(@"not active");
}

@end
```

How do I get `xAxis`’s value as an `int`. After getting its value as an `int`, I want to compare it in an if statement.

Thanks

Comment: This is not related to Xcode by any means. What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do string conversions in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169925/how-to-do-string-conversions-in-objective-c)

Comment: what about `self.xAxis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",accelerometerData.acceleration.x];`?

Comment: Are you trying to get an `NSInteger` with the `self.xAxis.text` value or are you trying to display the value as an integer in the label?

Comment: @CezaryWojcik I am trying to get the value of self.xAxis.text and compare it in an if statement

Comment: In that case, you can get an `int` value by doing `[self.xAxis.text intValue]`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this, but I prefer NSInteger so that in 64 bit devices, no performance is affected. NSInteger adapts itself depending on which bit processor the device is using.

```
[self.xAxis.text integerValue];
```

But if you insist on using ints

```
[self.xAxis.text intValue];
```

Comment: Could you tell me exactly how to write it, I am a beginner at Xcode

Comment: That is exactly how you write it... Could you elaborate?

Comment: I have an int x and a label xAxis. how would I write the above in my code

Comment: Those two methods return an NSInteger or an int, so you can just use that to replace it with whatever you need. Your question was how to turn self.xAxis.text into a integer number, so this is how you do it.

Comment: When I do what you are saying, an error shows up saying use of undeclared identifier self

Comment: That should not be happening. Could you post some extra code?

Comment: you're missing some close brackets, but I still do not know what you mean

Comment: I want to convert the value i get in xAxis into an int/double so that i can use the value of xAxis in an if statement comparing it to a number

Answer (score 0):

In the motion manager updates handler, `CMMotionManager` will provide a reference to a `CMAccelerometerData` object. That `CMAccelerometerData` object has a `CMAcceleration` property (`acceleration`). `CMAcceleration` is struct with `x`, `y`, and `z` components, each defined as a `double`. It looks like you are already using this to populate some labels’ text values. In this handler block, you already have a number representation of the x values. If you want to perform a check (if statement), this is the value you should be using.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];

    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1;

    if ([self.motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable]) {
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
            double x = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
            double y = accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
            double z = accelerometerData.acceleration.z;

            self.xAxis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", x];
            self.yAxis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", y];
            self.zAxis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", z];

            if (x > 0.5) {
                self.xAxis.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            } else {
                self.xAxis.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }
        }]; 
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Accelerometer is not available.");
    }
}
```

This will color the `xAxis` label red whenever the x value is over 0.5 and return it to black when it’s less than 0.5.

A few other things to note:

• Instead of calling `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), …` you can just get the accelerometer updates on the main queue directly. For what’s going on here, this is fine to perform entirely on the main thread.

• Only make one call to `[super viewDidLoad]`. `UIViewController` or whatever `UIViewController` subclass you’re subclassing likely does not expect `viewDidLoad` to be called multiple times, leading to undefined behaviour.